# tvOS checking if current focused ui element is a CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I'm trying to build my tvOS UI to look similar to the Apple TV home screen. When your focused on an app, a larger image shows up in the background. (top shelf area). The problem is, when I call the didUpdateFocusInContext method, the background image changes like it should, but only when navigating through the collectionviewcells. As soon as a I put focus on the tab bar, the app crashes with the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarButton' to CustomCollectionViewCell'.

I guess I just don't know how to check if the the ui element that is focused is a CustomCollectionViewCell. 
Here is what I have:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        let cell: CustomCollectionViewCell = context.nextFocusedView as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath? = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)

        mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath!.row])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are force-casting `context.nextFocusedView` to a `CustomCollectionViewCell`.
You can avoid the crash by checking if `context.nextFocusedView` actually is of the type you expect, and only then proceed to do whatever you want to do:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let cell = context.nextFocusedView as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath? = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath!.row])
    }
}
```

In general, be careful when force-unwrapping (`!`) or force-casting `as!` anything.